# AngularJS and null select values dependent on selection order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand a particularly odd behaviour that I've noticed in AngularJS.  Here's a basic snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```js
(function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('test', []);
  
  module.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.channels = [
      { name: 'A', id: 1, defSource: 'Y' },
      { name: 'B', id: 2 },
      { name: 'C', id: 3, defSource: 'Z' },
    ];
    $scope.sources = [ 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ];
    $scope.model = {};
    
    $scope.channelChanged = function() {
      $scope.model.source = $scope.model.channel.defSource;
    };
  }]);
  
})(angular);
        
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div>
    <label>Channel: <select ng-model="model.channel"
                            ng-options="channel.name for channel in channels"
                            ng-change="channelChanged()"></select></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Source: <select ng-model="model.source"
                           ng-options="source for source in sources"></select></label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>Channel = {{model.channel}}</div>
  <div>Source = {{model.source}}</div>
</form>
```

Observed behaviour (using Chrome) is this:

1. Select channel "A"; it auto-selects source "Y" as expected.
2. Select channel "B"; it auto-selects a null source as expected.
3. Select channel "C"; it remains with a null source instead of selecting "Z" as expected.
4. Select channel "A"; it selects "Y" as expected.
5. Select channel "C"; it selects "Z" as expected.
6. Select channel "B"; it selects null as expected but now the select contains two blank values.

In all cases the values in the model are correct; it's just the UI that ends up acting peculiarly.

I can work around this by explicitly providing an `<option>` element to represent null in the sources select, but I don't understand why this code has that behaviour, particularly with the two different behaviours of "C" depending on the prior selection, and why "A" doesn't do the same thing.  Is this a known AngularJS or Chrome bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the version of Angular you are using.  Try using the latest version of `1.3`, which is `1.3.17`.

```js
(function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('test', []);
  
  module.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.channels = [
      { name: 'A', id: 1, defSource: 'Y' },
      { name: 'B', id: 2 },
      { name: 'C', id: 3, defSource: 'Z' },
    ];
    $scope.sources = [ 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ];
    $scope.model = {};
    
    $scope.channelChanged = function() {
      $scope.model.source = $scope.model.channel.defSource;
    };
  }]);
  
})(angular);
        
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.17/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div>
    <label>Channel: <select ng-model="model.channel"
                            ng-options="channel.name for channel in channels"
                            ng-change="channelChanged()"></select></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Source: <select ng-model="model.source"
                           ng-options="source for source in sources"></select></label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>Channel = {{model.channel}}</div>
  <div>Source = {{model.source}}</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, that does seem to behave better.  I thought I read some dire warnings about 1.2 to 1.3 migrations somewhere, though.  It seems to be different now but the last time I checked 1.2 was still listed as the only "stable" version.

Comment: 1.3 is stable. We use it in production with no issues and have been investigating migrating to 1.4. Check the [migration guide] (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) and scroll down to "Migrating from 1.2 to 1.3" to see if any of the big changes will impact you.